add overlay to org mode entry headline that still shows when subtree is collapsed
I have an org mode entry/heading and want to add an overlay that appends some text to it (the text comes from the entry properties, but that's not necessary for this question). I'd like the overlay to be appended to the entry text. I can do that with the after-string property of overlays: I can do something like
    (when (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp)
      (let* ((beg (match-beginning 4))
             (end (match-end 4))
             (ov (make-overlay beg end)))
        (overlay-put ov 'name 'my-overlay-name)
        (overlay-put ov 'after-string "after")
        (overlay-put ov 'evaporate t)))

and if my entry looks like:
* the entry text
some stuff inside the subtree

then the above overlay code makes the entry look like the following when the subtree is expanded:
* the entry textafter
some stuff inside the subtree

That's what I want. But if I collapse the subtree, my overlay text is hidden by whatever mechanism org is using to make the subtree invisible: I see
* the entry text...

Note the ellipsis for the collapsed/invisible text.
There seems to be a complex interplay with text properties and overlays; I found this detailed reddit post on the details of overlays, their invisibility properties, and general text properties, but haven't figured out how to make my overlay still be visible when the subtree is collapsed.
Some partial solutions include:

using the before-string property for the overlay; then the overlay isn't in the part of the buffer hidden when I collapse the subtree, and so it still is shown;

using the disp property of the overlay to change the display of the entry text; since the subtree-collapsing functionality retains the entry text, the overlay for that text still is shown. But then edits to the entry text aren't shown unless I delete and re-add the overlay.


I've experimented with various forms of front-advance and rear-advance when calling make-overlay without luck.
Is there a nice way to get my additional text to display after the entry text, to still be shown when the entry is collapsed, and (perhaps?) also not interfere with the display of tags?

I started having the same issue after updating from an earlier org mode (don't have the version number at hand) to org mode 9.7 (on emacs 29.4). I noted that after-string is hidden when (setq org-fold-core-style 'overlays). Setting (setq org-fold-core-style 'text-properties) made the after-string visible again for folded headings. Not sure whether this is a long-term fix though, I would appreciate a more thorough solution!

This doesn't directly answer the question, but here's one approach: use org tags.
In my use-case, the overlay I want to add just included some additional context or information about the entry. It's exactly the kind of thing tags were intended for, and by using them, you're working "natively" inside the org ecosystem and API -- which means it works out of the box.
So: just use C-c C-q (or :, if you use speed keys). Org by default handles the overlay and general display of tags for an entry for you -- and, moreover, by using tags, you can do searches and so on.

Sometimes it's better to think in the box...

Hah! Indeed. "Hrm, should I write a bunch of my own off-the-cuff Lisp code, or should I rely on the hundreds of hours that org developers have put into this over the many years?" :)
